# Bootstrap 4 Popover not working for django Infinite Scroll

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [bootstrap popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/) to show some data, in my django site.

I have use [infinite scroll](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html) to show list of products.

We django iterate its pagination bootstrap popover don't works.

**page size : 3**

**total record : 12**

For 1st 3 record popover works but for next record it won't

**template :**

```
<div class="row infinite-container">
   {% for i in task %}
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 wow infinite-item">
          <a href="#0" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="data {{forloop.counter}}" class="grid_item">
          {{i.name}}
          </a>
      </div>
   {% endfor %}
   <div class="loading loader" style="display:none"></div>
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a class="infinite-more-link" style="display:none" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">More</a>
        {% endif %}
   </div>
</div>
```

**Js code :**

```
// for infinite scroll
var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
    element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
    onBeforePageLoad: function () {
          $('.loading').show();
     },
     onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
          $('.loading').hide();
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a waypoint JS and probably a popover JS loading at the end of the page. The popover will initialise the objects that are rendered. To do the same thing for the new objects, add the popover code to the waypoint JS - you can then even remove the separate popover JS from loading.

Here's the code of the new and improved waypoint JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
      element: $('.infinite-container')[0],

      offset: 'bottom-in-view',

      onBeforePageLoad: function () {
        $('.loading').show();
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
      },
      onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
        $('.loading').hide();
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
      }
    });
});
```